# Problema con un formulario HTML/JavaScript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un problema con un formulario HTML/JavaScript que luego es procesado y validado con PHP:

En mi sitio hay un formulario HTML, y el primer label es un select de múltiples opciones, sin embargo buscando con un poco de JavaScript estoy intentando hacer que cuando el usuario seleccione una opción se cambie la value automáticamente del field de abajo.

El problema es que cuando intento usar PHP para validar si el field está vacío, porque aunque el field cambia automáticamente a la value puesta en el select de opciones (Opción 1) si elimino el contenido que se puso automáticamente al seleccionar una de las opciones del select PHP continua tomando en cuenta a el value que se pone en el field automaticamente del select de opciones y no al input del usuario.

El selector de opciones es una referencia para que el usuario sepa que formato usar para acortar una URL de pagina de votacion de servidores de Minecraft: PE.

Ejemplo: Una opcion del select de opciones dice minecraftpocket-servers.com, cuando se seleccione el field de abajo (que es un input de texto) cambiara a la value="" que he definido que es https://minecraftpocket-servers.com/server/. El usuario debe simplemente ingresar el número que sigue, por ejemplo minecraftpocket-servers.com/server/38304, eso es todo.

Adjunto el código HTML, JavaScript y PHP:

**HTML**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="stepOneForm" name="createform" action="" method="post">
                            <p>URL Details</p><small>Complete required fields</small>
                            <div id="errors"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputIp" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Voting Site</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-lg-2">
        <select name="select" class="form-control" id="select">
          <option value="minecraftpocket-servers.com/server/">minecraftpocket-servers.com</option>
          <option value="minecraftpeservers.org/server/">minecraftpeservers.org</option>
          <option value="minecraftlist.org/pe-server/">minecraftlist.org/pe-servers</option>
          <option value="minecraft-pe-servers.com/servers/">minecraft-pe-servers.com</option>
          <option value="minecrafthub.com/pe-server/">minecrafthub.com/pe/servers</option>
         <option value="topg.org/server-">topg.org/minecraft-pe-servers/</option>
         <option value="minecraftpocketserverlist.eu/vote-">minecraftpocketserverlist.eu/</option>
        <option value="mcpeindex.com/server.php?id=">mcpeindex.com/</option>
        </select>
    </div><br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="longlink" id="inputIP" maxlength="150" placeholder="Path" required="">
                                    <p class="help-block">Enter the numbers or characters that follow of the mcpe voting site to access your server voting page</p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $('#select').change(function() {
         $('#inputIP').val($(this).val());
    }).change();
});   
</script>
```

**PHP**:

```
if(isset($_POST['longlink']))
{
echo ("Set!");

}
else {

echo ("Not set!");
exit;

}
?>
```

Espero haber sido lo más claro posible y además una resolución pronta de mi problema.

Comment: Puedes usar [focus](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp).

Answer (score 5):

Una forma de corregir el error es, cambiar tu código HTML y agregar el atributo explícitamente en el input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="longlink" id="inputIP" maxlength="150" placeholder="Path" required="">
```

Tambien cambiar un poco el JavaScript para no generar conflictos con otras librerías:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#select').change(function(){
    $('#inputIP').val(this.value);
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: Dejar explicito el atributo 'value'